# Get key and value from a JSONObject

Tags: java, spring-boot

Good morning everyone I want to get the "transactionid: and it "value" from a json object but I am getting some error I need your helps.
Ex:

request= {"amount":"5.0","msisdn":"233200343913","transactionid":"0000001853860636"}

Here is my code

```
                try{
                      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(request);

                        Iterator<?> keys = jsonObject.keys();
                        while (keys.hasNext()){
                            String key = (String)keys.hasNext();
                            JSONArray value = jsonObject.getJSONArray(key);
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

But the string key = (String)keys.hasNext() given error I need your help, please.

Comment: I think you want next() instead of hasNext() there.

Comment: Thanks, I did it but still, I can't get transaction-id and it value

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value of specific field, you can do it like this

```
    try{
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(request);
        String value = (String) jsonObject.get("transactionid");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you want to get all the fields and their values, you can do something like the following

```
    try{
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(request);
        Iterator<?> keys = jsonObject.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()){
            String key = (String) keys.next();
            String value = (String) jsonObject.get(key);
            System.out.println(key + " - " + value);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much that works